# CSS get 4 list items on one row

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have this page here https://artendijen.com/product-category/medium/ and there are 3 unordered list, the first list has 2 items, the second has 4 items and the third has 1 item. I am looking to get the 4 items in the second list to be on one row instead of 3 items in 1 row and 1 item on the next row. I do not understand why its like that:

```
<ul class="products" style="text-align:center;">
<li id="124" class="post-124 product type-product status-publish hentry instock"></li>
<li id="121" class="post-121 product type-product status-publish hentry instock"></li>
<li id="125" class="post-125 product type-product status-publish hentry outofstock"></li>
<li id="122" class="post-122 product type-product status-publish hentry instock"></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.woocommerce .products ul, .woocommerce-page .products ul, .woocommerce ul.products, .woocommerce-page ul.products {
margin: 0 0 1em;
padding: 0;
list-style: none outside;
clear: both;
}

.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {
float: left;
margin: 0 3.8% 2.992em 0;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
width: 22.05%;
margin-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest removing the right margin from the last li element.

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product:last-child, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: @user1269625 No, you should be ADDING that code to your CSS file.

Answer (score 2):

You could also just change the width of the images:

width: 21.05%;

This allows room for the margin, but keeps the four images on the same line.